# Is double (or multiple) summation under the integral always allowed?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I'm still trying to milk my favorite integral for all it's worth:

$$\int_0^1 x^a \ln^n x~dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(a+1)^{n+1}}$$

And the new thing I tried is to do a double summation under the integral, for example:

$$\int_0^1 x^l x^{bk} \ln^n x~dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(l+bk+1)^{n+1}}$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{cx} \ln^n x}{1+x^b}~dx=(-1)^n n! \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^k c^l}{l!~(l+bk+1)^{n+1}}$$

This series appears to be correct (checked by Mathematica), but I'd like to know when to expect trouble with this approach.

> When is double (or multiple) summation under the integral allowed?
>
> If the integral converges and the series on the right converges too, will they always converge to the same limit?
>
> Some reference would be appreciated too.

The particular problem I encountered - the integral existed, but the series on the right were full of infinities and didn't give the correct value of the integral. I can elaborate further on that, but I'd like a general answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always allowed?  No.  Often allowed?  Yes.  Check your calculus book (or your measure theory book) for theorems to apply.  Perhaps look for "exchange of limit and integral" or "integration term by term".